# Perf stat number of cycles and frequency scaling

Tags: linux, embedded, perf, energy, openblas

I've been doing small experiments using `perf stat` and `cpufreq-set` on an odroid-xu3 which is an embedded device with an Exynos chip (heterogeneous processor of A7 and A15 ARM cores). I used the BLAS lvl3 benchmarks to run my experiments and I've been pinning the tasks to the A15 core with the `taskset` utility. I also carefully checked that it is a single threaded implementation.

Hopefully the number of cycles should be the same when running at high or low frequency, but I can see a small variation, for instance running the GEMM kernel (matrix multiplication, 100 runs) at respectively 400MHz, 1000MHz and 1600MHz I obtain the following results:

```
7166620830 cycles
17.923790714 seconds time elapsed

7235173436 cycles
7.237463382 seconds time elapsed

7428037080 cycles
4.643897351 seconds time elapsed
```

You can see that even the duration is not really linear with the frequency (which is at least consistent with the measured number of cycles...). One hypothesis would be that the task is a bit memory bound but I have similar results with the single precision implementation... Do you have any idea of what could be the reason for this?

Edit: The matrices are 400 samples large and I use the environment variable OPENBLAS_LOOP (openblas benchmarks) to run it 100 times. I try to avoid other apps running, I can't tell there is 0% load but it's close. Do you suggest that I stop something special? Since it's already a mean over 100 experiments the variation at the same frequency is very low (<0.1%) and there is about 4% difference when I change the frequency and it's always a larger number of cycles for the highest frequency, so it does not look like it's more "noisy", it looks like something else happens at high frequencies.

Comment: It would probably need a bit more understanding about architecture of that processor. There might be a lot of reasons for that (memory -- how large matrices, how large memory and caches are available, ...). There might be overhead in kernel or in other apps running. It is really hard to say from this description.

Comment: How much variation do you see between runs at the same frequency?

Comment: To begin with, how do you know that your program execution is linear and 100% deterministic? If you have an OS with context switches, this seems highly unlikely. Same thing if you have interrupts.

Comment: Ok but linear against what? It's supposed to be 100% deterministic because it's a BLAS lvl3 kernel, there is no data-dependent behavior. It is just crunching data. So I guess if linear against frequency then yes it should be. I do of course have context switch and interrupts but I didn't expect much overhead since the machine is basically doing nothing apart this.

Comment: Emilien, you did count CPU cycles. CPU will cycle both when it is computing something and also when it is stalled and wait for data (from cache, from memory). Check not only cycles but also instruction counter which should be more stable (if this perf counter is implemented for your CPU), also exclude kernel mode from counting with `:u` suffix: `perf stat -e cycles:u,instructions:u,task-clock:u ./program`. Your memory controller and memory timings may change when you downclock your CPU Freq; memory have refresh timing which is calculated not from freq, but from ms (like full refresh in 64 ms).

Answer (score 0):

CPU cycles are required not only for calculation but also for waiting data from memory. (Yes,  GEMM is BLAS3 with very good arithmetic intensity on the [Roofline model scale](https://crd.lbl.gov/departments/computer-science/PAR/research/roofline/) and low amount of memory reads/writes, but there are still memory accesses, and they latency is not linear to CPU frequency.)

Try to check not only CPU cycles but also instruction counter which should be more stable (if this perf counter is implemented for your CPU), also exclude kernel mode (it may have some periodic tasks every 100 Hz or 300 Hz like scheduler) from counting with `:u` suffix:

```
perf stat -e cycles:u,instructions:u,task-clock:u ./program
```

(Also try to find some cache-miss events or memory-access event implemented for your cores, check raw encodings in core docs too and use `-e rHHHH` with found hex codes)

When you change CPU clock frequency, you may (or may not) also affect memory controller / memory bus frequency (this is specific to your SoC and boot configuration). DRAM memory (probably LPDDR3 in your "exynos 5422" SoC) have many timings which are calculated in memory bus frequency, but in reality they are from real memory data bank frequency and latencies.

Most of timings will be the same (or close) in absolute (ns) timings, but there is one which can affect your code cycles: [memory refresh timing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_refresh) - DRAM memory retain data only for short amount of time (charges leaks from data cells), something like full refresh every 32 microseconds (ms) or 64 ms (this changes with high temperature, usually there are two values - low temp and higher temp). 
With full data bank refresh command it will be inaccessible for some part of *time*, like for 2% or 5% (I have no exact value).

When changing you CPU frequency, you does not change refresh frequency (data should be always stable and refreshed as required by memory chip datasheet). But with 400 MHz CPU your calculation is longer and will see more refreshes; and with 1600 MHz calculation is short and will see less refreshes. Other effect - some memory requests may be stalled waiting for refresh to end.

So, there are some non-linear elements with different contribution (some are negative and other is positive for cycles at low freq):

- CPU frequency and DRAM refresh (absolute time requirements) is clearly not linear effect;
- CPU frequency and Linux kernel periodic tasks (they are scheduled to run some times per second, not per billion of cpu cycles)
- real data access [DRAM timings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_timings) ([RAS,CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAS_latency)) are measured in ns (but set up and reported in memory bus periods), and 1600 MHz CPU may have 100 cycles to get first byte from memory, but 400 MHz CPU may have 60 cycles to get first byte from memory.

The last effect looks like the most notable in your results - low cycles for low MHz, high cycles for high MHz. With high frequency CPU may stall much more cycles to wait some tens of ns from memory to precharge / activate row / select column. With low frequency same ns of memory latency will be converted to low amount of slow CPU cycles.